# CSV TO JSON using dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

**Please refer this dataweave window image :- [dataweave window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xjqT.png)**

I am trying to transform a CSV TO JSON using dataweave but even for the simplest of transformations it is creating a null tag automatically. I can see that in the preview window. When I run this application I am getting this error 
*

> Exception stack is:
>   1. 452 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.CharArraySourceReader:21 (null)
>   2. 452 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler
>   (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32
>
> ******************************************************************************** Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   452   at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.CharArraySourceReader.lookAheadAscii(CharArraySourceReader.scala:21)
>     at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.parser.CSVParser.parse(CSVParser.scala:132)
>     at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.parser.CSVParser.elementAt(CSVParser.scala:61)
>     at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.parser.CSVParser.contains(CSVParser.scala:38)
>     at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.CSVRecordsValue$$anon$1.hasNext(CSVReader.scala:58)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.toStream(Iterator.scala:1188)    at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.CSVRecordsValue$$anon$1.toStream(CSVReader.scala:56)

This is the sample csv I am using

```
SpreadsheetKeyEmployee,Position,EffectiveDate,BonusPlan,Amount,Currency,IgnorePlanAssignment
1,18211,2016-05-01,BONUS_PLAN1,150,USD
2,18212,2016-05-01,BONUS_PLAN2,150,USD
3,18213,2016-05-01,BONUS_PLAN3,150,USD
4,18214,2016-05-01,BONUS_PLAN4,150,USD
```

I think i might be doing some mistake with the reader configuratuion (for csv) there is a similar issue discussed in the forum but this isnt helping either    https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/36378/dataweave-example-of-csv-to-json.html

Comment: Need to see your config, there's probably something simple with the hooking up.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried recreating your scenario but unable to replicate it, here is the dataweave configuration that I have used and it works.

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="e4e1b720-5d25-4b36-8406-cf7d6bfc7d6a" doc:name="CSV to JSON">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
         %output application/json
         ---
         payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
              SpreadsheetKeyEmployee: payload01.SpreadsheetKeyEmployee as :number,
         Position: payload01.Position,
         EffectiveDate: payload01.EffectiveDate,
         BonusPlan: payload01.BonusPlan,
         Amount: payload01.Amount,
         Currency: payload01.Currency,
        IgnorePlanAssignment: payload01.IgnorePlanAssignment
        })]]></dw:set-payload>
  </dw:transform-message>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that dataweave cannot handle window line endings correctly. Can you try to replace the windows new line delimiter with \n only as follows:

```
#[payload.replace("\r\n", "\n")]
```

You can place the above MEL expression in a set-payload before dataweave.

Comment: It throws an error....**Exception stack is:
1. [Error: unable to resolve method: java.lang.String.get(java.lang.String) [arglength=1]]
[Near : {... payload.get('contents') ....}]**

Comment: I've modified the expression to make use of the payload directly. The idea is to replace all \r\n in your payload, so you need to modify the MEL expression according to your use case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the csv file and map it to JSON object in dataweave component.
Check the link below

https://dzone.com/articles/csv-xml-json-in-mulesoft

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.